# Paperclip synatx; which way is the proper way of handling validates_attachment_content_type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, paperclip-validation

I'm using the ruby gem paperclip to handle image attachments and I'm adding `validates_attachment_content_type` to my books model. I just have a question on syntax.

Which is the proper way of doing the above?

`validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"], message: "Only jpeg, png, and gif images types are allowed"`

or

`validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /^image\/(png|gif|jpeg|jpg)/, message: "Only jpeg, png, and gif images types are allowed"`

To me (total beginner) the first seems cleaner/clearer. Or does it not matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with either one, I prefer the first one:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"], message: "Only jpeg, png, and gif images types are allowed"
```

If you prefer to use a regex to validate, then use the second one.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the answer. Hopefully I'm in the right direction with this, the `:content_type => xxx` is the rails 3 way of doing `content_type: xxxx` correct?

Comment: No not really, on rails 3 you'd have `attr_accessible :image ` and on rails 4 that would become `has_attached_file :image` so only way you mount your image attribute changes, not the validation portion.